# my program reads from the file but cant find the words

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

So my program knows where the file is and it can read how many words it has, however, I am trying to compare words to count the occurrences of a word that i will use with a scanner.
The program says i can't convert string to a boolean which i understand but how would i be able to make it happen?
can I get an answer why it runs but doesn't allow me to find the word to look for 
thanks

```
       import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class wordOccurence {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  {
int wordCount=0;
int word =0;
Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter file name");
System.out.println("Enter the word you want to scan");
String fileName=scan.next().trim();
Scanner scr = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
// your code goes here ...
while(scr.nextLine()){
    String word1 = scr.next();
    if (word1.equals(scr)){
        word++;
    }

}
System.out.println("Total words = " + word);

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At present you are only checking if there is a next line available:

```
while(scr.hasNextLine()){
```

but you are not fetching it. Its like you are staying at the same position in the file forever.

To fetch the next line, you can make use of

```
scanner.nextLine()
```